# React-native-router-flux: is there an OnEnter method?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have spent my entire morning reading the [docs](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux), but can't find simple `OnEnter()` method, like in `react-router`. I'm using the latest version.

I need to fetch some resources when entering some specific `Scene`. Any idea?

Comment: componentWillMount will be called first time a scene is pushed but if a scene is revisited via pop, there is no react lifecycle method call. There are many requests on github for this feature. It's not implemented.

Comment: @sumanj You mean the target component's, or the `Scene` itself's `componentWillMount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use either constructor or componentWillMount functions in the scene component.

```
constructor(props){
    fetch(url)
    then(doThings())
}
```